# Is it guaranteed that blur() event happens before the focus() when giving focus to a new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have two input fields.
One has focus, then I click on the other input field.

Is it **guaranteed** that the `blur()` event (of the first element that lost focus) happens **before** the `focus()` event (other element got focus) ?

Comment: Yes. You cannot have two elements in focus at the same time, although you can have an unlimited number of elements set to blur at same time.

Comment: You could just use `focus()` event on both input fields, and then you'll know that the `blur()` happened on the other input when one is selected.

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As of W3C draft [DOM3 Events](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dom3events/raw-file/tip/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-focusevent), the specification tells you:

Focus Event Order

> The focus events defined in this specification occur in a set order
>   relative to one another. The following is the typical sequence of
>   events when a focus is shifted between elements (this order assumes
>   that no element is initially focused):

```
> User shifts focus
> 1.    focusin Sent before first target element receives focus
> 2.    focus   Sent after first target element receives focus 
> User shifts focus
> 3.    focusout    Sent before first target element loses focus
> 4.    focusin Sent before second target element receives focus
> 5.    blur    Sent after first target element loses focus
> 6.    focus   Sent after second target element receives focus
```

Note that the statement that there cannot be two elements with focus is not completely correct; although I am not aware of desktop environments that let two widgets have focus at the same time, the specification lets an implementation decide that:

> Other specifications **may** define a more complex focus model than is described in this specification, including allowing multiple elements to have the current focus.

Also this is worth mention:

> A host language **may** define specific elements which might receive focus, the conditions under which an element **may** receive focus, the means by which focus **may** be changed, and *the order in which the focus changes*. (italic is mine).

However, beware that Chrome does not follow the standard - instead the order is `blur, focusout, focus, focusin`. You can test this using [this page](https://output.jsbin.com/muruju/). Webkit browsers may have the same issue. The `focusin` and `focusout` events are supported since [Firefox 52](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/52).

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes.  Otherwise two elements could have focus at the same time which should never be possible.

Comment: actually the specification lets an implementation have multiple simultaneously focused elements (although I am not aware of any *existing* implementation of this)