# Is it possible to get id of an element which was responsible for making the other element to loose focus, inside blur or focusout event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input element with id = 'ele1'. I click on any other element,let it be 'ele2'. Now in blur event or focusOut event of 'ele1', I need to get the Id of the element 'ele2'.

$(this), document.activeElement, e.target.id inside blur event gives the value of current element 'ele1', because in blur event, the active element will still be 'ele1' and not 'ele2'. Is it possible to get id 'ele2' in 'ele1' blur event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that's possible, as the second element receiving focus is the last step in the blur/focus sequence,  as [answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340091/is-it-guaranteed-that-blur-event-happens-before-the-focus-when-giving-focus)

But you could give each element a class, then store the first element and do something with it when the second element receives focus.

```
$('.element').on('blur', function() { document.lastFocusedElement = this; })
$('.element').on('focus', function() { document.lastFocuedElement = ele1; this = ele2;  })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this can be done; if focus of the second element is triggered by a mouse click, then you could take advantage of the "mouse down" event hook which fires before the "blur" event on the currently focused element:

```js
$("#ele2").mousedown(function() {
  
  // Select the currently focused element in the
  // document before the focus change takes effect
  // as a result on the click event
  const prevId = $("*:focus:first").attr("id");

  console.log(`Prev focus ${ prevId }, Next focus ${ $(this).attr("id") }`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Focus on ele1 or ele3, then switch focus to ele2 by mouse click</p>
<input placeholder="ele1" id="ele1" />
<input placeholder="ele2" id="ele2" />
<input placeholder="ele3" id="ele3" />
```

If you're looking for a general solution that works for all events the cause a change in focus (ie, tab presses, etc), then I think this will involve a bit more work. Something like this might do the trick for you:

```js
var currentFocus = null;

$("*").focus(function() {
  
  // If this element focus does not match current focus ..
  if(!$(this).is(currentFocus)) {
      
    // If current focus is valid ..
    if(currentFocus) {
    
      // Detect a switch in focus from some prior element to
      // the current element
      const prevId = $(currentFocus).attr("id");
      console.log(`Prev focus ${ prevId }, Next focus ${ $(this).attr("id") }`);
    }
    
    // Update current element as current focus
    currentFocus = $(this);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  margin:1rem;
  border:1px solid red;
}

*:focus {
  outline:2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<p>Switch focus between ele1, ele2, and ele3 by tab, click, etc</p>
<input placeholder="ele1" id="ele1" />
<input placeholder="ele2" id="ele2" />
<input placeholder="ele3" id="ele3" />
<input placeholder="something else" id="ele4" />
<textarea id="ele5"></textarea>
<select id="ele6"><option>Opt</option></select>
<button id="ele7">Button</button>
<div id="ele8" tabindex="0">Div with tab index</div>
<div id="ele9">Div with no tab index (won't trigger focus())</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was little wrong when posting the question. If I am sure of which element I click as next, then I can work with mouse down. but If I am not sure which element I click next exactly then mouse down can not be used, I am not interested to use window.click, because this method will load on every click. Please help

Comment: Hey you're welcome - the second snippet in my answer avoids the use of `mousedown` , does that suit? Or are you wanting to avoid having to attach this functionality to specific/known elements?

Comment: the second snippet in your answer, provides previous focus and next focus with in mentioned elements('ele1','ele2','ele3'). But my requirement is different where I need the focus of next element which made previous element to loose focus and next element can be anything and may need not be mentioned.

Comment: @Yashasvi sorry for delay (was asleep!), if I understand correctly, you want to further generalise this. I've updated the second snippet - does that better meet your requirements?